# Unit testing controllers practices

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

How should I unit test controllers? First of all, I mock the database results, that's clear. But then what? Should I rewrite the code from controllers, and test all queries against mocks? Or rather call the controller classes, and test the overall result? I mean, for example, having this class:

```
class User {

   public function foo()
   {
      // query 1
      // query 2
      return $someresults;
   }

}
```

Should I test it like that:

```
class TestUser {

   public testFoo()
   {
      // query1
      // assertions
      // query2
      // assertions
      // results asserions
   }

}
```

Or rather like:

```
class TestUser {

   public function testFoo()
   {
      $user = new User($mockEntityManager);
      // assertions on $user object
   }

}
```

What's the proper way to do this? Testing all queries doubles the code, and generates problems with external queries in repository classes (not sure if I can mock that). Testing general results is ok, but methods in controllers return view templates, so I'm not sure how do I test database responses there.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best approach is to define controller as services (as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)) so you don't need a webcrawler for handling request/response but only interact with his trhow mocked services.

Check [this article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/06/symfony2-testing-your-controllers/) for further detail

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't unit test controllers, as they do not contain any logic itself. You should need to functional test them, so you can verify it behaves the way you want it.